# getAttribute or dataset with variable attribute

Tags: javascript, dataset, getattribute

i'm having a bit of a hard time; hopefully you guys can help me.

I'm rendering a button element with many data-sets via PHP -- so the amounts of data-sets and value may vary depending on the request. So if i have a data-product_name , there could be several ones, what makes it different is the "prev"  (can be prev or next ) and the number

Example HTML:

```
<button id="prev_product" data-count="4" data-prev_0_product_title="name" data-prev_0_product_url="name" .... data-prev_2_product_title="name2"... data-prev_3_product_title="name3"... onclick="myFunction(prev)" >
```

My javascript function is set the following way:

```
var get_value = document.getElementById('prev_product');

var total_products = get_value.dataset.count;


    for (counter = 0; counter < total_products; counter++){
        var single_product_title = instance+'_'+counter+'_product_url';

        var single_product_url = instance+'_'+counter+'_product_title';
        var single_thumb_url = instance+'_'+counter+'_thumb_url';
        var single_dim_length = instance+'_'+counter+'_dim_length';
        var single_dim_width = instance+'_'+counter+'_dim_width';
        var single_dim_height = instance+'_'+counter+'_dim_height';


        var prod_parameters = {};

        prod_parameters[counter] = {
                product_title   : get_value.dataset.single_product_title ,
                product_url     : get_value.dataset.single_product_url,
                thumb_url       : get_value.dataset.single_thumb_url,
                dim_length      : get_value.dataset.single_dim_length,
                dim_width       : get_value.dataset.single_dim_width,
                dim_height      : get_value.dataset.single_dim_height
            };
}
```

When i console.log the prod_parameters ,all the keys output properly, but the values are "Undefined"

if i call the dataset."actual name", this works properly.  However, i need this function to work with variables and loop.

I've also tried using the getAttribute() function, with no luck either.. Note that all single_product_'name' are all string, i've confirmed this.

Please help,

Thanks!

Comment: Why so many attributes? Could make an ajax call to get this or use one attribute with JSON in it and just parse that JSON or write the same json to  a javascript  variable as object and access that object directly. Seems a shame to break up well structured data into a less structured set of attributes

Comment: that is true, however, now that i've hit this wall, it would be nice to see if there is a way to pass a variable on this dataset API name. that way, js code can be a bit more dynamic.

Comment: Ok but you had to break up an array on server to do this, now you have to put that array back together. Why not skip the destructure and rebuild? `<div data-json='<?=json_encode($array)?>'>`